# What kind of regression model would best suit this scenario?

Tags: regression

I'm new to statistics so this may seem an obvious question for you guys.
I have created a survey to collate peoples opinions on how U.S anti-money laundering regulation has impacted their financial privacy.

The survey is completely anonymous if you are interested and found here:

https://forms.gle/9Fwm1nH9E8P4ioPR9

So I am trying to model financial privacy loss (dependent variable) against U.S anti-money laundering regulation such as the Patriot Act / Bank Secrecy Act ...(the independent variables). In total I have 4 independent variables or 4 pieces of regulation.

In my model the independent variables can impact the dependent variable in 3 ways:  **Weak, Moderate, Strong.**

From what I understand this scenario is trichotomous and not binary, and also discrete not continuous as there is no in-between)

For example: The Bank Secrecy Act has had a **strong** impact on financial privacy loss.

So my question is: What kind of regression model would best suit this scenario?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

One example would be this to create a vector named 'Bank Secrecy Act' and use it as an independent variable. This variable is categorical taking values in the set $\{weak, strong, moderate\}$. You can use one-hot encoding to create dummy variables, which can then be used as an input in a regression model. Since you have 3 states you need 2 dummy variables. One example would be:

- $[0,1]$ indicates $weak$
- $[1,0]$ indicates $strong$

The absence of dummies, $[0,0]$, is the base case. In this example this correspond to $moderate$ effect. Note that most packages create these implicitly, so you only need to create the input vector prior to fitting the model.

Comment: Thanks for replying Akylas that sounds like a great suggestion, when you say most packages are you referring to software such as SPSS as I have been advised to use that? Once again, I really appreciate you taking the time to answer this.

Comment: For example the `glmnet` package in R does this automatically. I would suppose SPSS has the same functionality, although I've never tried it to be honest.